# Iniciar actividad desde aplicación en otro celular vía internet

Tags: java, android, activity

El tema es que deseo iniciar una actividad por medio de otra aplicación que está instalada en otro dispositivo y también pueda iniciar esa actividad enviando variables por internet. Para explicar mejor realicé un gráfico que pueda explicar el desarrollo de la actividad que se desea realizar.

[image: Actividad a realizar]

Answer (score 2):

Si, es posible, bajo de algunas circunstancias. Hay una variedad de metodos de iniciar el contacto, te lo explico en un caso en que uso un sms para iniciar el dialogo entre los dispositivos.

Primero implemento un escuchador en el manifesto (en este caso escucha a un sms que cumple con algunos criterios):

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".controller.SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Luego implemento el `Listener`

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SmsReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // construir el mensaje del sms
        Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage messages = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            messages = createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0],intent.getStringExtra("format"));
        } else {
            messages = createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        }
        Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());
        // el criterio en mi caso de uso es un numero configurado en mis preferencias
        // por supuesto puedes cambiarlo por algun dato que filtras del mensaje
        String origin = SystemService.getInstance().getPrefs(context).getString("alarm_phone","");

        // aquí compruebo si la sms cumple con mi criterio y armo un intent
        // tu puedes armar este intento libremente a tu gusto
        if (messages.getOriginatingAddress().endsWith(origin)){
            Intent resend = new Intent(I.SMS_RECEIVED);
            resend.putExtra("displayOrigin", messages.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
            resend.putExtra("origin", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
            resend.putExtra("message", messages.getMessageBody());
            resend.putExtra("dateSent",messages.getTimestampMillis());
            context.sendBroadcast(resend);

            //does not abort on Marshmallow so what the heck
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

En la actividad que arrancas (o activas) con el intent puedes iniciar la comunicación con la otra app en la forma que te conviene, por ehemplo comunicación por UDP, sobre un Redis, sobre una conneción TCP en un servidor que provees - tu decides el sabor. Y por supuesto puedes remplazar el `Listener` por otra señal entrante que un sms, en el caso ideal algo que te permite determinar de quien llegó la solicitud y que actividad hay que llamar (si existen más que una opción).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. 
Entiendo que debo trabajarlo por un método BroadcastReceiver pero todavía me queda una duda y es la siguiente. De que forma el dispositivo se da cuenta que la actividad esta llegan por intermedio de otro aplicativo ya que debe emitir una respuesta a ese mismo celular. Analizando el código veo que es una recepción de SMS y una respuesta seguida por el número de teléfono que viene con el SMS.

Comment: En el caso del SMS tienes los datos que ya te entrega el sistema, como numero de entrada, pero obviamente también puedes incluir datos en el texto del SMS, que solamente una forma, puedes captar otros eventos con un `BroadcastReceiver`. También hay varios métodos para contectarte al otro dispositivo. Yo solamente te he ofrecido la solución como arrancar tu actividad usando un `BroadcastReceiver`, ahora te toca de desarrollar un sistema que define los canales como quieres conectar los dispositivos y empezar a implementarlo. De eso pueden nacer más preguntas, pero todo a su tiempo.